# JLabel en JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

Tengo un Buscaminas con un JMenu en la parte superior y un GridLayout que es el buscaminas, pero me gustaría añadir un JLabel en la parte superior y no se como.

Lo he probado pero se me muestra por debajo dejo código y foto.

```
  public Buscaminas(Controlador c) {


            this.controlador = c;
            FILES=controlador.tauler.getFiles();
            COLUMNES=controlador.tauler.getColumnes();
            BOMBES=controlador.tauler.getBombes();

            configuracio();
            botons = new Boto[FILES][COLUMNES];
            configGraella();
            this.pack();
            this.setVisible(true);

            setLayout(null);

            barra=new JMenuBar();
            setJMenuBar(barra);
            menu=new JMenu("Dificultad");
            barra.add(menu);

            facil=new JMenuItem("Facil");
            facil.addActionListener(this);
            menu.add(facil);

            normal=new JMenuItem("Normal");
            normal.addActionListener(this);
            menu.add(normal);

            dificil=new JMenuItem("Dificil");
            dificil.addActionListener(this);
            menu.add(dificil);

            pers=new JMenuItem("Personalizado");
            pers.addActionListener(this);
            menu.add(pers);

           label= new JLabel("Bombas");
           label.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 20);
           add(label);
        }
```

En la imagen lo que señalo es el JLabel creo...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mejor organiza la GUI usando dos contenedores, algo así como un header y un body, en el header metes las etiquetas que necesites ya sea la de minas restantes, tiempo y el botón con emoji y en el body, al cual le aplicas un GridLayout agregas los botones.

Comment: También ten en cuenta, que un JPanel por defecto es FlowLayout, y te colocará los elementos uno a continuación del otro, así simplemente en el panel que tengas el JMenuBar, añades la etiqueta o label `panelDondeTengoLaBarra.add(label)`